# Avoid webcrawlers running middleware

Tags: php, laravel

When a user enters my website I create a cart with the help of middleware like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $cartId =  $request->cookie('cartid');
    if($cartId == null) {
        $cart = new Cart();
        $cart->save();
        $cartId = $cart->id;
        $newCoockie = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $currentCart = Cart::find($cartId);
        if($currentCart == null){
            $cart = new Cart();
            $cart->save();
            $cartId = $cart->id;
            $newCoockie = true;
        }
    }
    $ip = "onbekend";
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $cart->ip = $ip;
    $cart->save();
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('cartid', $cartId);
    return $next($request)->withCookie($cookie);
}
```

It al works fine but now I have a problem with webcrawlers. when viewing my database I can see there are alot of carts created by webcrawlers like [this](http://webmeup-crawler.com/) they are  sending an request every 30 seconds for the last few days!  How should I avoid creating a cart for al the webcrawler request? .

Comment: Unless your site is significantly different from most of the web shops on the internet, the majority of your visitors will be guests, meaning they will browse without actually adding something to the cart or buying anything, and possibly never come back. So it's not a good idea to store the cart contents in the database for guests, because most of them will just remain empty entries (just like what the bots create). I suggest you keep the cart contents for guests in the session, and only store cart data in the database for logged in users (that might actually come back and use that cart data).

Comment: @Bogdan its not about the cart contents, i just give every user an cart so ajax calls are easy (every user has a cart)

Comment: It may be easier, but it's a bad approach. You need to create a cart when you actually need one, otherwise you end up with your current issue. If you make an AJAX call that needs to modify the cart, you can have a simple condition that checks if that user has a cart and if not create it (then on the next AJAX call from the same user the cart will already be there). That way bots can't create carts because they can't run actions that modify the cart (since they're asynchronous and require interaction that they most likely won't initiate).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some reason why every request needs to have an active Cart, you might want consider creating the cart only when someone actually tries to put something into it.

Comment: I mostly use Ajax, so when sending a request to add to cart it's nice to have a cart by default, else I need to add a function to create a new cart on every request that does something with the cart, and return a response with a new cookie.